# Manipulating a record data

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

I am looking for a way to take data from one table and manipulate it and bring it to another table using an SQL query.

I have a Column called NumberStuff that has data like this in it:

```
INC000000315482
```

I need to cut off the `INC` portion of the number and convert it into an integer and store it into a Column in another table so that it ends up looking like this:

```
315482
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: We will need more information.  How does the two tables link together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use the Replace function. Either in [TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) or as a Derived Column [Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx) in SSIS.

TSQL

```
SELECT REPLACE(T.MyColumn, 'INC', '') AS ReplacedINC
```

SSIS

```
REPLACE([MyColumn], "INC", "")
```

This removes the character based data. It then becomes an optional exercise in converting to a numeric type before storing it to the target table or letting the implicit conversion happen.

Comment: I have decided to use `REPLACE([MyColumn], "INC", "")`. It works for the most part but i need it as an integer. Any ideas? Or would you possibly know how to append another derived column that is an integer to column that is replacing the INC? like have the end result making the two numbers `315482` and `083113` become an integer of `315482083113`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest version of what you need.

```
select cast(right(column,6) as int) from table
```

Are you doing this in a SSIS statement, or?...is it always the last 6 or?...

This is a little less dependant on your formatting...removes 0's and can be any length (will trim the first 3 chars and the leading 0's).

```
select cast(SUBSTRING('INC000000315482',4,LEN('INC000000315482') - 3) as int)
```

Comment: It could be less or more. my thought is that if i can just get rid of the `INC` it would dump the 0s being converted into an integer. I am doing it in SSMS right now, but i believe i will be converting in over to SSIS eventually. Thanks!

Comment: substring and len will make it a little less dependant on set length.  Editted into answer.

Comment: That seems like it would work for that specific record. But i have hundreds of records. Is there a way that i would be able to identify this through the column name so it changes all of them and puts the modified data into another column as an integer?

Comment: I hardcoded for that one...you can use the column name instead of 'inc00000etc...'.  select cast(SUBSTRING(column_name,4,LEN(column_name) - 3) as int)

Comment: That is what i figured. I just wanted to double check that they are able to be used interchangeably. I will try it when i have a chance and check back and mark you post as an answer.